# Collapse bootstrap 3 en columnas dinámicas no funciona bien

Tags: bootstrap-3

Tengo un **solo row** que se llena dinámicamente con **varios col-4** y dentro de éstos tengo collapse's. Ojo, cada uno tiene su target y su id diferentes, para abrir el correspondiente (ese no es problema).

[image: Se ve así]

Cuando clickas en los de izquierda o derecha, se muestra bien como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando clickas en **alguno de los de enmedio** se desplaza las cols y se muestra como lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Algún truco para que al clickar en un collapse de enmedio no se desplacen los siguientes col's?

Lo tengo ahora con el for y la información vendrá de la BD y se usará foreahc, claro. El código es este:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 8 ;$i++){
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <article class="blog-news-single">
         <div class="blog-news-img">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="imagen.jpg" alt="image">
         </div>
         <div class="blog-news-title">
           <button 
             data-toggle="collapse" 
             data-target="#demo<?php echo $i;?>">
             Ver más  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
           </button>

           <div id="demo<?php echo $i;?>" class="collapse">
              Lorem ipsum dolor text....
           </div>
        </div>
     </article>
  </div> }
```

Comment: Deberias implementar el codigo, ya que asi podremos tomarlo, encontrar una solucion y responder... las imagenes es una soporte pero no todo

Comment: No encuentro dónde editar mi pregunta. Una disculpa, se me olvidó pegar el código

Comment: arriba de estos comentarios en la parte derecha hay 3 link el de medio dice "editar" ese es :V